# vector of std::variant types to std::tuple

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdtuple, std-variant

I am working on vector of std::variant types. Is there a way to convert it to std::tuple of the values holded by given std::variants ?

```
typedef std::variant<type1, type2,...> a_union;
std::vector<a_union> vec;
```

For example, I would like to have tuple like:

```
std::tuple<typeX, typeY, typeX,...>
```

Where members are types holded by consecutive variants in vector.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time (at compile time) the types your vector will contain?

Comment: Do note that `std::tuple` is a compile time object while `std::vector` is a run time object.  If you don't know what the type the variants will hold at compile time, or how many objects you will have in the vector at compile time, then making the tuple is basically impossible.

Comment: vector has dynamic size. Each variant inside can have any type, so what is seance to create tuple (which is static type) for that? IMO this [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and you should explain why you need this strange thing, what actually you are trying achieve (not how you think you can achieve it)?

Comment: This is only possible if you know for sure that `vector::size()` contains the same number of entries as the `tuple<...>` type will have, and if you know exactly which types from the variant each element will contain. Though this _can_ be done, it's not likely a stable or good solution for whatever the problem is you are trying to solve

Answer (score 3):

This might be a solution for you, it uses optional and returns nullopt if the vector has incorrect values

```
#include <optional>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
 
template<typename ... T, size_t ... Index>
std::optional<std::tuple<T...>> to_tuple(const std::vector<std::variant<T...>> & vec,
                                         std::index_sequence<Index...>)
{
    if (sizeof ... (T) != vec.size())
        return std::nullopt;
        
    if (not (...&& std::holds_alternative<T>(vec[Index])))
        return std::nullopt;
    return std::tuple<T...>(std::get<T>(vec[Index])...);
}

template<typename ... T>
std::optional<std::tuple<T...>> to_tuple(const std::vector<std::variant<T...>>& vec)
{
    return to_tuple(vec, std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments accurately state that this is probably an XY problem - a tuple requires compile-time information about the types of the data at each index that a vector of variants does not.

But, if you're willing to *provide* that information at the callsite, it's pretty straightforward to use parameter pack expansion to map a list of types to a string of calls to `std::get<>`.

You can provide that list of types by assuming the order of types in the variant to be the desired variant types at each index, as jo-art 's answer does. Here is a way to do by just providing a list of types you expect the tuple the vector to contain, in case they are different:

```cpp
template<typename... Ts, typename Container, std::size_t... Is>
auto vector_to_tuple_impl(Container&& items, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<Ts>(items[Is])...);
}

template <typename... Ts, typename Container>
std::tuple<Ts...> vector_to_tuple(Container&& items)
{
    return vector_to_tuple_impl<Ts...>(items, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
}
```

(there's no error handling here, it will throw an `std::bad_variant_access` if you get the types wrong, and undefined behavior if you extract more elements than exist)

It's the same basic strategy: Use `std::index_sequence_for` to turn a parameter pack into an expandable parameter pack of container indices (0, 1, 2, etc...). The integer sequence pack and the type pack are expanded together to get the item at each index, and call `std::get` to extract the value.

usage:

```cpp
    using SimpleVariant = std::variant<std::string_view, int>;
    std::vector<SimpleVariant> some_list { "hello", 42, "goodbye" };
    auto as_tuple = vector_to_tuple<std::string_view, int, std::string_view>(some_list);
```

proof of concept:
https://godbolt.org/z/cGEW5s